# remove all HTML formatting from a string

Tags: c#, string

I am trying to compare 2 strings but i just realized that one has some html formatting already.

How can i get these two strings to match when doing string1 == string2. (NOTE: i dont know what the HTML formatting is going to be upfront)

```
string1 = "This is a test";
string1 = "<font color=\"black\" size=\"1\">This is a test</font>";
```

Comment: dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: That is not valid C#. `string1 = "This is a test"` - see the `"`?

Comment: The HTML version is also not valid C# - you need to escape the inner `"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Load the html into [Html Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net), and extract only the text.

```
string html = "<html><body><div>test</div></body></html>";
HtmlDocument document = new HtmlDocument();
document.LoadHtml(html)
string text = document.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

This will not remove the content of `<script>` nodes, but you can easily remove the script nodes first.

Comment: Obligatory link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: @Mikael Svenson - how do extract only the text using the HTML Agility Pack ?

Comment: @ooo: I added a sample on how to do it.

Comment: HtmlAgilityPack is pretty awesome for parsing HTML.

Comment: @Mikael Svenson - can i simply shove in <font color=\"black\" size=\"1\">This is a test</font> into this code above as it doesn't seem to work. hw.Load() seems to be looking for a URL as the parameter

Comment: @ooo use HtmlNode.CreateNode(myHtmlString) to create a new HtmlNode and then get the InnerText of the instance

Comment: @Mikael Svenson - thanks . .this worked but i found one issue.. i put that issue in question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3425554/does-the-html-agility-pack-work-on-internal-text

Comment: Are you sure that `InnerText` removes *all* HTML tags, rather than just the outermost pair?

Comment: Yes. Just like it will in the DOM object on a webpage (except innerText is not cross platform javascript). InnerText gives back all text inside the container you start from. <body><div>lala</div><div>lala</div></body> gives the same result as <body><div>lala<div>la<span>la</span></div></div></body>

Answer (score 0):

```
string newText = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(OldHtmlTextHere, "<[^>]*>", string.Empty);
```

Comment: Hehe, cool. This may still fail though in case the inner text has character entities like &amp; . Then again, I am not sure if the accepted anser's solution does take care of that.

Comment: @MartinMaat I don know, I use this function in all of my projects. never let me down!

Answer (score -5):

Check out system.web.Httputility.HTMLdecode

Comment: This will not let you extract only the text, or remove your tags.