# Running into an issue trying to extract the text from a snippet of HTML

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

i am using the HTML Agility pack to convert

```
 <font size="1">This is a test</font>
```

to

```
 This is a test
```

using this code:

```
 HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(html);
 string stripped = doc.DocumentNode.InnerText;
```

but i ran into an issue where i have this:

```
 <font size="1">This is a test &amp; this is a joke</font>
```

and the code above converted this to

```
This is a test &amp; this is a joke
```

but i wanted it to convert it to:

```
This is a test & this is a joke
```

does the html agility pack support what i am trying to do?  why doesn't the HTML agiligy code do this by default or i am doing something wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode()` on the output.

However, note that `InnerText` will include HTML tags that may be contained inside the outermost tag. If you want to remove *all* tags, you will have to walk the document tree and retrieve all the text bit by bit.

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&nbsp;") gives me a space as expected.