# Extracting the letter in between tags

Tags: c#

Can anyone guide me how to extract words in between tags.
For example:

```
<body>hello</body>
```

(in C#)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

Answer (score -2):

I guess he meant to say word between **tags**. You should use regular expression for the same.

Comment: You **shouldn't**, and even if you **should**, an example is warranted.

Comment: I agree with Michael. You should not encourage people to edit XML data with regular expressions. There are much richer and appropriate tools for parsing XML data.