# i mean extracting the word between two tabs

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [extracting the letter in between tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3562997/extracting-the-letter-in-between-tags)

okie let me give an example we have a file,where i need to open it in c# and scan and extract information ,like i want hi to be extracted  which is between  tag so only i want that to be extracted and copied to other file ,so what can i do??....and how to start about

```
<REFER> abcd</REFER>
<BODY>hi</BODY>
<p1>hello</p1>
```

Comment: Please edit your previous question instead of creating a new one with meaningless topic

Comment: I agree. I suspect "How do I parse a word between two elements" might be a slightly better topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this may be a trivial example, but if your document structure gets any more complex than this, I'd highly recommend [`HtmlAgilityPack`](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

For the example given, you'd use it like this:

```
string html = "<REFER> abcd</REFER><BODY>hi</BODY><p1>hello</p1>";

var doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.LoadHtml(html);

HtmlNode root = doc.DocumentElement;
HtmlNode body = root.SelectSingleNode("BODY");

string extracted = body.InnerText;
```

That may seem like overkill; but like I said, if the document structure gets any more complex (I can't imagine that the documents you'll be parsing really look like the example), you'll be glad you did it.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use an [HTML-Parser](http://www.google.de/#hl=de&source=hp&q=HTML+parser+.NET&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&fp=361bae3dd12d8501) (pick one) and then use it to retrieve the content between the tags.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I'd start with looking in the **System.IO** namespace in order to learn how to read and write files...

Your data looks like it may be XML, so look at the **XmlDocument** class in **System.Xml** or the Linq **XDocument** class. If it's not XML then you're going to have to parse it yourself, so read up on the **String** class.