# Need regular expression to remove <a href="xx">Name</a> tags from a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

Need regular expression to remove the a tag from the following url `<a href="http://example.com">Name</a>` to output only the string `"Name"`. I am using C#.net.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: [Obligatory?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 30):

This will do a pretty good job:

```cs
str = Regex.Replace(str, @"<a\b[^>]+>([^<]*(?:(?!</a)<[^<]*)*)</a>", "$1");
```

Comment: nice, not sure why it was not marked as answer, it perfectly does exactly what is asked in the question

Comment: +1 for non-recursive nesting poetry! :)

Answer (score 3):

You should be looking at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/). RegEx works on almost all cases but it fails for some basics or broken Html. Since, the grammar of HTML is not regular, Html Agility pack still works perfectly fine in all cases.

If you are looking for just one time this particular case of anchor tag, any above RegEx would work for you, but Html Agility Pack is your long run, solid solution to strip off any Html tags.

Ref: [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this one.  It has not been tested under all conditions, but it will return the correct value from your example.

```
\<[^\>]+\>(.[^\<]+)</[^\>]+\>
```

Here's a version that will work for only  tags.

```
\<a\s[^\>]+\>(.[^\<]+)</a\>
```

I tested it on the following HTML and it returned **Name** and **Value** only.

```
<a href="http://xx.com">Name</a><label>This is a label</label> <a href="http://xx.com">Value</a>
```

Comment: I have other html tags in the string so I need code to remove only the link(a) tag.The html outputted is created by me so the chances of getting broken html does not happen.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Priyank that using a parser is a safer bet. If you do go the route of using a regex, consider how you want to handle edge cases. It's easy to transform the simple case you mentioned in your question. And if that is indeed the only form the markup will take, a simple regex can handle it. But if the markup is, for example, user generated or from 3rd party source, consider cases such as these:

```
<a>foo</a> --> foo # a bare anchor tag, with no attributes
                   # the regexes listed above wouldn't handle this

<a href="blah"><b>boldness</b></a> --> <b>boldness</b>
                   # stripping out only the anchor tag

<A onClick="javascript:alert('foo')">Upper\ncase</A> --> Upper\ncase
                   # and obviously the regex should be case insensitive and
                   # apply to the entire string, not just one line at a time.

<a href="javascript:alert('<b>boom</b>')"><b>bold</b>bar</a> --> <b>bold</b>bar
                   # cases such as this tend to break a lot of regexes,
                   # if the markup in question is user generated, you're leaving
                   # yourself open to the risk of XSS
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is working for me.

```
Regex.Replace(inputvalue, "\<[\/]*a[^\>]*\>", "")
```

Comment: I count 9 HTML tags that start with a, and there's probably a million and one other ways how this will fail on arbitrary input.

Comment: This worked for my needs, simply stripping tags from a single static HTML doc. Obviously it fails for a number of edge cases but not sure that's enough to warrant the down-votes.