# Conditionally replace section of string

Tags: c#, regex

I have a question relating to the manipulation of strings in C#.

Say I have a string:

```
"Today I ate a <a href="link here "> chocolate </a> at the <a href=\"another link here"> supermarket</a>. It was a brand of <a href=\"3rd link">Contoso</a>
```

I would like to make it:

```
"Today I ate a  chocolate at the supermarket. It was a brand of Contoso.
```

I can remove the `</a>` part of it, but am unsure of how to remove everything and anything between the `<a href` and the `>`

How would I go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a good answer here: [Need regular expression to remove <a href="xx">Name</a> tags from a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5792522/need-regular-expression-to-remove-a-href-xxname-a-tags-from-a-string)

Works too!

Feel free to post any better, more efficent methods.

Answer (score 0):

`Regex` is probably the best option,But if you don't want to use `Regex` it will be quite fiddly to parse the string the way you want.

One idea could be to Split the string by `</a>` then grab all the chars on ethier side of `<a` and `>`

```
 var result = new string (input.Split(new string[] { "</a>" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .SelectMany(s => s.Where((c, i) => i < s.IndexOf("<a") || i > s.IndexOf(">"))).ToArray());
```

So I would stick with the `Regex` if its working for you as its a lot easier than using string options