# Regular Expression help

Tags: regex, c#-4.0

I'm pretty hopeless with regualr expressions and im struggling with what is probable an increadably simple one!

I have a string which contains many instances of something like this:

```
<li><a  href="BEEF.com">STEAK</a></li>
```

I know the value of 'STEAK' and im looking for the value of the href attribute.
This value can be anything.
I'm using C# .net 4.0

Thanks for any help

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

[HTML agility pack](http://www.codeplex.com/htmlagilitypack)

instead (don't regex html)