# Removing styles and JavaScript from HTML with C#

Tags: javascript, .net, html, c#-4.0

What I want to do is to strip away all JavaScript and CSS snippets from an HTML page and get pure HTML code. How can I do it correctly?

Comment: There is no simple way to do this as far as i understand, you will just have to go through your code, see what it does, then rewrite it

Comment: I think since all css and js will be tagged by the `style` or `script` tag, you can just run through the html file, remove anything between, and including `<style>` and `</style>` and `<script>` and `</script>`

Answer (score 2):

You could always use the [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to try to parse the HTML, remove the offending script/style nodes, and output the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Another similar post with a popular answer [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

An alternative, perhaps not as elegant but safer option would be to pass the html to a third party service and interpret the results

Answer (score 0):

thanks, unfortunatelly it's possible to put JS and CSS to HTML without using HTML tags. You can do it with HTML `style` attribute for CSS, and You can bind JS to `event` for a button for example with a attribute too. I thought there is elegant, automatic way to clean HTML... :/