# Regex Pattern in C#

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)
>   [Regex Pattern in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300729/regex-pattern-in-c-sharp)

I have this kinda input how can i convert it into C#

```
Input = <!--EVENT-GALLERY-VIEW WIDTH=500 --> 
Output = "<widget:EventList id=\"EventList1\" Width=\"500\" runat=\"server\" />"

Input = <!--EVENT-GALLERY-VIEW WIDTH=500 CATEGORY=SPORTS --> 
Output = <widget:EventList id=\"EventList1\" Width=\"500\" runat=\"server\" Category=\"Sport\" />"
```

Follwing code works fine for first case but not for second **How can i Alter var pattern = @"(\w*)(\s*))*(\s*)(-->)";**

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var result = "<!--EVENT-GALLERY-VIEW WIDTH=500 -->";
            var pattern = @"(<!--)(\s*)(EVENT-GALLERY-VIEW)(\s*)((WIDTH)(=)(?<value>\w*)(\s*))*(\s*)(-->)|(<!--)(\s*)(EVENT-GALLERY-VIEW)(\s*)((WIDTH)(=)(?<value>\w*)(\s*))*(\s*)(-->)";
            var replaceTag = "<widget:EventList id=\"EventList@@id\" Width=\"@@value\" runat=\"server\" />";

            result = RegexReplaceWithUniqueTag(result, pattern, replaceTag);
        }

        static string RegexReplaceWithUniqueTag(string result, string pattern, string replaceTag)
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex(pattern);
            MatchCollection mc = regex.Matches(result);
            for (int i = mc.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                string newreplaceTag = replaceTag;
                newreplaceTag = newreplaceTag.Replace("@@id", i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
                if (mc[i].Groups["value"] != null)
                    newreplaceTag = newreplaceTag.Replace("@@value", mc[i].Groups["value"].Value);
                result = result.Remove(mc[i].Index, mc[i].Length);
                result = result.Insert(mc[i].Index, newreplaceTag);
            }
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `?` (0 or 1) operator to mark a statement as optional, like so:

`(CATEGORY=(?<category>\w*))?`

This will find 0 or 1 occurrences of `CATEGORY=[WORD]`.

Some other regex operators that you might find useful are:

`+` (1 or more)
`*` (0 or more)

You can find more info on regex characters [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).