# How to remove missing tags from HTML source in Asp.net

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

Sometime it has been seen that the HTML source that we receive from some website are not having proper tag ending, and that affect our UI.
So, like

```
<br /><p>hello the para start here </p> <p>some text and no ending tag
```

And there is no ending tag .

I want to retain the HTML format and want this like

```
<br /><p>hello the para start here </p> some text and no ending tag
```

One more thing is that sometimes we get the end tag at the start that should also be resolved by the algorithm.

Comment: is it HomeWork??like making a HTML compiler...

Comment: I am working on a Article translator and want to retain the article original formatting, it is for GabbleOn.com

Comment: See http://tidy.sourceforge.net/ or http://sourceforge.net/projects/tidynet/ - it will effectively attempt to convert the HTML into conformant (X)HTML. Or see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags?rq=1 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/846994/how-to-use-html-agility-pack - there are plenty of resources for this on Stack Overflow.

Comment: There are a ton of HTML parsing libraries out there which would be infinitely better at this than regex. (There's also an obligatory Stack Overflow post illustrating this, but I won't bother linking it.) These parsers will do their best effort to translate broken HTML into not-broken HTML. But in the end there might be some things that are just too broken and the author simply needs to fix it.

Comment: For this small thing I don't want to use the whole **Html Agility Pack**

Comment: @AbdurRahman: If you want it to give you fixed and valid HTML you're going to have to use a full on HTML parser like HTML Agility pack I'd imagine...

Answer (score 0):

Hey guys I thought for a long time and finally I have code for my problem, i am posting it here so that other can get benefit from this ....

```
 public static string RemoveIncompleteTags(string source, string tag)
    {
        source = source.Replace("  ", " ");
        source = source.Replace("/n", string.Empty).Replace("/r", string.Empty).Replace("/t", string.Empty);
        source = source.Replace("<" + tag + "></" + tag + ">", string.Empty);
        source = source.Replace("<" + tag + "> </" + tag + ">", string.Empty);
        source = source.Replace("<" + tag + ">  </" + tag + ">", string.Empty);
        Dictionary<int, string> oDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        string[] souceList;
        Dictionary<int, string> final = new Dictionary<int, string>();
        bool opening = false;
        bool operate = false;
        source = source.Replace("  ", " ");
        source = source.Replace(">", "> ").Replace("<", " <");
        source = source.Replace(" >", ">").Replace("< ", "<");
        source = source.Replace("  ", " ").Replace("  ", " ");
        souceList = source.Split(' ');
        for (int i = 0; i < souceList.Length; i++)
        {
            string word = souceList[i];
            if (word.ToLower() == "<" + tag.ToLower() + ">")
            {
                opening = true;
                operate = true;
            }
            else if (word.ToLower() == "</" + tag.ToLower() + ">")
            {
                opening = false;
                operate = true;
            }
            if (operate)
            {
                if (opening)
                {
                    oDict.Add(i, word);
                    final.Add(i, word);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (oDict.Count != 0)
                    {
                        oDict.Remove(oDict.Last().Key);//.ToList().RemoveAt(oDict.Count - 1);
                        final.Add(i, word);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // need not to add to the output string 
                        // code if you want to log
                    }
                }
                operate = false;
                opening = false;
            }
            else
            {
                final.Add(i, word);
            }
        }
        if (final.Count > 0)
        {
            if (oDict.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (var key in oDict.Keys)
                {
                    final.Remove(key);
                }
            }
            StringBuilder fText = new StringBuilder();
            final.ToList().ForEach(wd =>
                {
                    if (wd.Value.Trim().Length > 0)
                        fText.Append(wd.Value.Trim() + " ");
                });
            return fText.ToString().Trim();
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

thanks...

Comment: That's a brave effort, but trying to process (possibly malformed) HTML using regular expressions or string patterns leads to a world of pain. dash's suggestion above about tidy seems like a better path.