# A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client (

Tags: c#, asp.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client)

I got error messages:

```
 A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client 
 (ctl00$MainContent$textboxError=...
```

after I run asp.net (C#) web application. how can I fix it?

Here is my code.

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Net;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace SMS
{
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textboxRecipient.Width = 400;
    textboxMessage.Width = 450;
    textboxMessage.Rows = 10;
    textboxError.Width = 400;
    textboxError.Rows = 5;

    textboxError.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    textboxError.Visible = false;
    textboxError.Text = "";

    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        textboxRecipient.Text = "+85593840396";
        textboxMessage.Text = "Hello World!";
    }
}
protected void buttonSendOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (textboxRecipient.Text == "")
    {
        textboxError.Text += "Recipient(s) field must not be empty!\n";
        textboxError.Visible = true;
        return;
    }


    string ozSURL = "http://127.0.0.1"; //where Ozeki NG SMS Gateway is running
    string ozSPort = "9501"; //port number where Ozeki NG SMS Gateway is listening
    string ozUser = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tenh"); //username for successful login
    string ozPassw = HttpUtility.UrlEncode("tenh123"); //user's password
    string ozMessageType = "SMS:TEXT"; //type of message
    string ozRecipients = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textboxRecipient.Text); 
    string ozMessageData = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(textboxMessage.Text); 

    string createdURL = ozSURL + ":" + ozSPort + "/httpapi" +
        "?action=sendMessage" +
        "&username=" + ozUser +
        "&password=" + ozPassw +
        "&messageType=" + ozMessageType +
        "&recipient=" + ozRecipients +
        "&messageData=" + ozMessageData;

    try
    {

        HttpWebRequest myReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(createdURL);


        HttpWebResponse myResp = (HttpWebResponse)myReq.GetResponse();
        System.IO.StreamReader respStreamReader=new 

      System.IO.StreamReader(myResp.GetResponseStream());
        string responseString = respStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
        respStreamReader.Close();
        myResp.Close();

        //inform the user
        textboxError.Text = responseString;
        textboxError.Visible = true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        textboxError.Text = "Ozeki NG SMS Gateway Server is not running!";
        textboxError.Visible = true;
    }

  }
  }
  }
```

I already add codes below to my web.config :

```
   validateRequest="false" and requestValidationMode="2.0"
```

Comment: Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825025/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the, this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11838852/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client and countless other questions here. You've asked this same question 3 times.. why are you asking the same thing 3 separate times?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I also know that this is a third time but the other questions also does not have accepted answers and no proper solution.

Comment: Does this error occur every time you click the "buttonSend" Button? For the First time also it doesn't work?

Comment: this error is occur when i click on button Send in second time

Comment: @Shree Khanal: i asked this question because it's not work for their answer.

Comment: @ToeurTenh The Second time when you click the button, The value "textboxError" is getting posted to the server. Can you use a label to display the "responseString" instead of showing in a textbox? Or can you use Javascript to Clear the value of the textbox before posting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know why `validateRequest="false"` is not working. **Error Reason:** Because you are getting data from a web page which contains Html tags and textbox text property does not allow to assign html strings to it, so you have to use a method which converts html tags to their equivalent code.
Use [HTML.Encode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) Method while assigning `responseString` to the `textboxError.Text`. This method converts potentially unsafe characters to their HTML-encoded equivalent.

```
textboxError.Text = Server.HTMLEncode(responseString);
```

Comment: thanks for your nice answer. but after i used textboxError.Text = Server.HTMLEncode(responseString); i got error codes like this &lt;Responses&gt;&lt;Response0&gt;&lt;Action&gt;sendMessage&lt;/Action&gt;&lt;Data&gt;&lt;AcceptReport&gt;&lt;StatusCode&gt;0&lt;/StatusCode&gt;&lt;StatusText&gt;Message accepted for delivery&lt;/StatusText&gt;&lt;MessageID&gt;03a22ae5-e604-4fb6-9670-336294905a9d&lt;/MessageID&gt;&lt;Recipient&gt;+85593840396&lt; i used HTML.Encode only on textboxError.Text = Server.HTMLEncode(responseString);

Comment: this method converts html tags to their corresponding codes see the msdn documentation. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx Also you can use Regex to remove html tags. `String result = Regex.Replace(responseString, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);` for more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: also you can use asp:literal control instead of text like this `<asp:Literal ID="lit" runat="server" Mode="PassThrough" ></asp:Literal>` Then you dont have to use Html.Encode method or rejex to remove html. read more about it on msdn

Comment: i used String result = Regex.Replace(responseString, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty); to remove html tage after i got this error: sendMessage0Message accepted for delivery75d9c6f1-515f-43f6-9b7b-5c2482ce95e8+85568922903. what is problem?

Comment: they don't tell about line. this error alert when i click on send button

Comment: if use aspliteral control then you don't have to use regex try it. I'm sure it will work, take an example from msdn

Comment: i did not used asp:literal. i normally just used asp.net control, so?

Comment: if i used asp:literal , should i used HTML Encode?

Comment: when i run my web application it display this (<Responses><Response0><Action>sendMessage</Action><Data><AcceptReport> ) so i want to encode this, how can i do?

Comment: if you use asp:literal control then you don't have to use Html.Encode function.

Comment: Thanks for all your answer. now i want to asked one more question. How to get Panasonic Camera IP in asp.net (C#)?

Comment: plz post a new question.

Comment: in this account i can not post new question. i don't know why. Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See http://goo.gl/C1Kwu to learn more.