# Google maps api in updatepanel - HTML in InfoWindow do not show up on refreshing update panel

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a Google map canvas inside an `update panel`. The map refreshes its content(location) every time the update panel refreshes. I need to show some content in tabular format in the `InfoWindow`.
The problem is that if I use `html tags` in InfoWindow it shows up only for the first time when the application loads and when I am refreshing the update panel the application freezes. But if I use plain strings in InfoWindow the content shows up properly every time.
Here's the code in **C#** where I am generating the tabular content of InfoWindow.

```
sb.Append("<div id=\"content\"><table>");
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>" + dr[0].ToString() + "</td></tr>");
}
sb.Append("</table></div>");
```

This doesnt works after updating the update panel. However the below code works:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    sb.AppendLine(dr[0].ToString());
}
```

I am putting the generated string into a `hiddenfield` and using it in **js** file like this:

```
var contentString = document.getElementById('InfoWindowString').value; 
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
})
```

Can any one please tell me where I am going wrong.

Comment: Could there be some invalid HTML in `dr[0].ToString()` that would cause problems with the table tags?

Comment: @duncan No. I checked it using - sb.AppendLine("<tr><td>" + "test" + "</td></tr>"); and even then it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the Javascript console in the browser and found the error message `A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client`
Using the following Stackoverflow links - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11839244/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81991/a-potentially-dangerous-request-form-value-was-detected-from-the-client) I found that **validateRequest** is to be set to **false** in the Page directive: `validateRequest="false"`

Hope this helps anyone else facing the same problem.