# Stopping XSS when using WebAPI

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-4.0

I have a controller which accepts

```
public class MyModel
{
   [MaxLength(400)]
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

I have a WebApi Post Action

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post(MyModel viewModel)
{
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
                return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);                 
            ...
}
```

And a get action.

Since the content is written out by javascript rather than directly in a view the exact content was getting written out, also no asp.net warnings about dangerous content kicked in.

I want to protect against XSS. At the moment I am doing

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Regex.Replace(p.Message, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty))
```

in the Get action. (Taken some code from [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags))

Is there any protection built in to Asp.Net I should be using?  Are there any attributes I can decorate my model with?

I noticed this http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2012/06/25/announcing-the-june-2012-release-of-the-ajax-control-toolkit.aspx but clicking through to http://wpl.codeplex.com/ is seems to be very badly reviewed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/117512/should-i-html-encode-all-output-from-my-api

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AntiXSS in ASP.Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37923431/antixss-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As your code stands right now, a user could just inject JavaScript that doesn't use a script tag.

There is a [common list](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet#URL_string_evasion) of XSS vulnerabilities that could be used.

Right now you accept a 'string', and all you parse out are HTML tags. Unfortunately, there are a lot of XSS attacks that don't rely on HTML.

For instance, adding the following to a GET Request in Firefox: `%22onmouseover=prompt%28%29//` will allow the person to inject JavaScript.

Your best bet is to use the [AntiXss library from Microsoft](http://wpl.codeplex.com/), and specifically encode the parameters for GET and POST requests.

(I have to head to work, but I'll post more code later on how to do this).

Comment: I looked at that but the reviews put me off it http://wpl.codeplex.com/releases/view/80289#ReviewsAnchor, if this is the best library available will have another look...

Answer (score 12):

**NOTE:** Please read the whole answer, I switched from AntiXss library to HtmlSanitizer. Also test test test! I'm not a security expert.

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.security.antixss.antixssencoder?view=netframework-4.7.2), you can just do the following in your `web.config`:

```
<httpRuntime encoderType="System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder" />
```

You don't need to install the AntiXss library anymore since it is now included in .NET 4.5.

**UPDATE:**

Turns out it wasn't enough to set the encoderType in web.config, what I ended up doing was intercepting the deserialized json and validating it like so:

```
public class AntiXssConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(string);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var stringValue = (string) reader.Value;
        ThrowIfForbiddenInput(stringValue);
        return stringValue;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var token = JToken.FromObject(value);
        token.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    private static void ThrowIfForbiddenInput(string value)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value))
        {
            return;
        }

        var encoded = AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode(value, true);
        if (value != encoded)
        {
            throw new Exception("Forbidden input. The following characters are not allowed: &, <, >, \", '");
        }
    }
}
```

Use converter like this:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.Converters = new List<JsonConverter>
{
    new AntiXssConverter()
};
```

If the data contains any illegal characters, I simply throw an exception because I don't want to accept it in my backend. Others might want to simply sanitize the input.

Another thing to do just in-case, is to configure WebAPI to escape HTML output, like so:

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.StringEscapeHandling = 
    StringEscapeHandling.EscapeHtml;
```

This covered everything for me.

**SECOND UPDATE:**

I've decided to change from using the AntiXss library to using [HtmlSanitizer](https://github.com/mganss/HtmlSanitizer) because AntiXss was way too restrictive by encoding all foreign characters (ä, ö, etc...) and I couldn't get it to allow them even though the unicode block was in the whitelist.

The other nice thing about this library is that it's unit tested with the OWASP XSS Filter Evasion Cheat Sheet. [Click here for more info](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/.NET_AntiXSS_Library).

**THIRD UPDATE:**

If you decide to use the JsonConverter way above, it's possible to bypass it by simply setting a different Content-Type on the client-side (such as "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") and the request would go through to the server.

In order to avoid this, I cleared all other formatters, leaving only the JSON one, like so:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

Then, in order to ignore my XSS converter on specific properties (like Password fields for example), I found a great solution from the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53402583/1469494), which was to create a dummy "NoConverter" class which would default to using the default converter for specific properties:

```
public class NoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
}
```

Usage:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(NoConverter))]
public string NewPassword { get; set; }
```

I may still have missed something, I'm by no means an expert web developer, but it has been an interesting ride... :-)

Comment: How does this work for you? AntiXssEncoder.HtmlEncode encodes the string to Html so how can it ever match values in a web api when the data received is JSON?

Comment: @Thierry If you read my whole answer you'll notice I switched to HtmlSanitizer library by the way. But regarding your comment, I don't understand the problem? Obviously if you're comparing a string that was sanitized to a non-sanitized one it won't match, but that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 7):

There are two main schools of thought to protect against XSS attacks.

- Output encoding
- Input validation

For output encoding, Server.HtmlEncode(p.message) should do the trick (so what you have currently in your example will work, don't need to do the Regex replace if you don't want to.  The output encoding will prevent XSS).  Here I am assuming you want to do HTML encoding and not Url encoding or the like.

Looks like you are using the .NET MVC framework.  You could use [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to preform white-list validation (allow only safe characters) versus black-listing.  I would look at using the [RegularExpressionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.regularexpressionattribute%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).  For example:

```
public class MyModel
{
   [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z''-'\s]{1,400}$", ErrorMessage = "Characters are not allowed.")]
   public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll second recommending whitelist validation. You can create a custom ValidationAttribute

Answer (score 3):

For Stopping XSS when using WebAPI. It is better to use middleware to avoid/ stop the XSS. I found the one best link/blog please prefer the below link to added middleware.

https://www.loginradius.com/blog/async/anti-xss-middleware-asp-core/

In this link all step are covered please gone through that and implement.

Only One issue facing to add the middleware into Startup.cs class.

```
app.UseAntiXssMiddleware();
```

Instead of that I used below syntax to add middleware in Startup.cs class.

```
app.UseMiddleware<AntiXssMiddleware>();
```

Answer (score -3):

#### To protect against the web's security shortcomings:

Try to mitigate damage.  Use antiforgery tokens, ensure that you only accept ssl for certain actions. Ensure that cookies are appropriately secured. Overall, minimize the attack surface and put roadblocks to make it harder.

#### To protect against users input:

Parametrize user input, if you can't parametrize, encode, but be very careful with encoding, many many exploits have been caused by improper encoding. Encoding also depends upon where and how the input is going to be used.
  Constrain and validate user input, ensure that server only accepts certain domains of input. And as before, understand all the ways the input is going to be used.

#### Handling response from the web server:

Ensure that you got an OK status from the web server.  If you didn't, handle each response appropriately.  Generally jquery.ajax gives you the option to handle all the responses with done, fail, always, and statusCode, refernce jquery documentation about how to do this properly.

### Three things you need to do:

1. Utilize the @Html.AntiforgeryToken() in your forms and its corresponding [ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute] attribute to decorate your classes and/or methods.
2. Handle input from the user correctly. Everywhere that data is touched, the context needs to be considered if it needs to be encoded or parametrized, or otherwise validated, constrained or modified.
3. Handle the responses from the web server correctly.

`[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method | AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public sealed class ValidateAntiForgeryTokenAttribute : FilterAttribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {
        public Task< HttpResponseMessage > ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Func< Task< HttpResponseMessage > > continuation)
        {
            try
            {
                AntiForgery.Validate();
            }
            catch
            {
                actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage 
                { 
                    StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden, 
                    RequestMessage = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request 
                };
                return FromResult(actionContext.Response);
            }
            return continuation();
        }
        private Task< HttpResponseMessage > FromResult(HttpResponseMessage result)
        {
            var source = new TaskCompletionSource< HttpResponseMessage >();
            source.SetResult(result);
            return source.Task;
        }
    }`

Comment: That's MVC not WebAPI