# C# JsonConvert using the default converter instead of the custom converter

Tags: c#, json.net

I have a class as follows that has a custom `JsonConverter`:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(TheShapeSerializer))]
public class TheShape : IShape {
//....
}
```

I cannot change the class. The way the custom serializer works is not appropriate for my needs.

Is there a way to serialize an instance of TheShape using the default serializer instead of TheShapeSerializer?

Along the same lines, is there a way to have multiple converters that can be selected at serialization time based on a given condition?

Comment: You could try using another converter when directly calling serialize/deserialize `var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, new MyCustomConverter())` That way you have greater control over the process.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I am checking to see if my suggested comment is viable and not seeing anyone with similar issues.

Comment: `JsonConverter` applied using attributes supersedes `JsonConverter` applied via settings.  From the [docs](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm): *The priority of which JsonConverter is used is member attribute, then class attribute, and finally any converters passed to the JsonSerializer.*.  You'll need to use a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples).

Comment: @dbc that is a good find in the docs. I was unaware of that.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The order in which JsonConverters are selected is [documented](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm#JsonConverterAttribute) as follows:

> The priority of which JsonConverter is used is member attribute, then class attribute, and finally any converters passed to the JsonSerializer.

Thus you cannot disable a `JsonConverter` applied via [`JsonConverterAttribute`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverterAttribute.htm) using [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm).  Instead, you have the following options.

Firstly, if your `TheShape` is being referred to directly by some type you control, you could grab `NoConverter` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739105/3744182) to *[Selectively use default JSON converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39738714/3744182)* and apply it to the referring members using `JsonConverterAttribute` or [`JsonPropertyAttribute.ItemConverterType`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute_ItemConverterType.htm), e.g. as follows:

```
public class ShapeContainer
{
    [JsonConverter(typeof(NoConverter))]
    public TheShape Shape { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(ItemConverterType = typeof(NoConverter))]
    public List<TheShape> Shapes { get; set; }
}
```

Now `NoConverter` will supersede `TheShapeSerializer` for the properties where it is applied, and cause Json.NET to fall back on default serialization.

Secondly, if you cannot add member attributes to types where `TheShape` is used, you could create a [custom contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/contractresolver.htm#CustomIContractResolverExamples) that overrides [`DefaultContractResolver.ResolveContractConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_ResolveContractConverter.htm) and returns `null` for `TheShape`.  First define the following contract resolver:

```
public class ConverterDisablingContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    readonly HashSet<Type> types;

    public ConverterDisablingContractResolver(IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        if (types == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        this.types = new HashSet<Type>(types);
    }

    bool ContainsType(Type type)
    {
        return types.Contains(type);
    }

    protected override JsonConverter ResolveContractConverter(Type objectType)
    {
        // This could be enhanced to deal with inheritance.  I.e. if TBase is in types and has a converter then
        // its converter should not be used for TDerived -- but if TDerived has its own converter then it should still be
        // used, so simply returning null for TDerived would be wrong.
        if (types.Contains(objectType))
            return null;
        return base.ResolveContractConverter(objectType);
    }
}
```

Then, define a static member somewhere as follows, for performance reasons described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33557737/3744182):

```
static IContractResolver shapeResolver = new ConverterDisablingContractResolver(new[] { typeof(TheShape) });
```

And serialize as follows:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = shapeResolver,
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settings);
```

Demo fiddle showing both options [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sen17w).

*Along the same lines, is there a way to have multiple converters that can be selected at serialization time based on a given condition?*

Obviously you could add different converters to `JsonSerializerSettings.Converters` depending on some runtime condition.  But if you want to supersede statically applied converters with runtime converters, you would need to set up your types appropriately, e.g. by using `OverridableJsonConverterDecorator` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41216067/3744182) to *[Why Json.net does not use customized IsoDateTimeConverter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6384132/3744182)*.

Comment: This is great. I used the ContactResolver approach since the first solution was not relevant for the reasons you said and it worked perfectly