# C# Newtonsoft.Json Custom Deserializer

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm working with an API that is returning results to me in a different way than I'm used to dealing with, and seemingly non-standard.

For example, here's a snippet of Customer data:

```json
{
    "CustomerID": {
        "value": "EXAMPLE"
    },
    "CustomerCurrencyID": {
        "value": "USD"
    }
}
```

That "value" property seems very unnecessary, so I would like to see if I can just bypass that all together and deserialize that JSON into an object like so:

```cs
class Customer {
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    public string CustomerCurrencyID { get; set; }
}
```

I'm currently working on writing a custom JsonConverter to handle this, so if I'm heading down the right path just let me know, but any tips/tricks here would be much appreciated!

Comment: That, or create the C# object representing the format you want, write the C# code to map from bad object to good object, and serialize that.  I would opt for that over a custom serializer, but that's mostly personal preference.

Comment: @Jonesopolis The thing is, I'm leaning more towards a custom converter because when I want to send my object BACK to the API, it would need to be in their format.

Comment: Makes sense.  Or map both ways - an extension class with two methods `static GoodApiObject ConvertFromBadAPIObject(this badApiObject)` and `static BadApiObject ConvertBackToBadApiObject(this goodApiObject)`.  It can be good practice to wrap third party integrations in objects you own, depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this with a generic [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) such as the following:

```
public class WrapWithValueConverter<TValue> : JsonConverter
{
    // Here we take advantage of the fact that a converter applied to a property has highest precedence to avoid an infinite recursion.
    class DTO { [JsonConverter(typeof(NoConverter))] public TValue value { get; set; } public object GetValue() => value; }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(TValue).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => serializer.Serialize(writer, new DTO { value = (TValue)value });

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => serializer.Deserialize<DTO>(reader)?.GetValue();
}

public class NoConverter : JsonConverter
{
    // NoConverter taken from this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39739105/3744182
    // By https://stackoverflow.com/users/3744182/dbc
    // To https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39738714/selectively-use-default-json-converter
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)  { throw new NotImplementedException(); /* This converter should only be applied via attributes */ }
    public override bool CanRead => false;
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override bool CanWrite => false;
    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer) => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Then you can apply it to your model as follows:

```
class Customer {
    [JsonConverter(typeof(WrapWithValueConverter<string>))]
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }
    [JsonConverter(typeof(WrapWithValueConverter<string>))]
    public string CustomerCurrencyID { get; set; }
}
```

Demo fiddle #1 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5QHWUD).

Or, if you want *all* strings to be wrapped in a `{"value": <string value>}` object, you can add the converter to [`JsonSerializerSettings.Converters`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonSerializerSettings_Converters.htm) when serializing and deserializing:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    Converters = { new WrapWithValueConverter<string>() },
};

var model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Customer>(json, settings);

var json2 = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Demo fiddle #2 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/NJCPaM).

If your value is an `enum` and you want to serialize it as a string, you can replace `NoConverter` with [`StringEnumConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Converters_StringEnumConverter.htm) by using the following:

```
public class WrapEnumWithValueConverter<TEnum> : JsonConverter where TEnum: Enum
{
    // Here we take advantage of the fact that a converter applied to a property has highest precedence to avoid an infinite recursion.
    class DTO { [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] public TEnum value { get; set; } public object GetValue() => value; }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType) => typeof(TEnum).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => serializer.Serialize(writer, new DTO { value = (TEnum)value });

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
        => serializer.Deserialize<DTO>(reader)?.GetValue();
}
```

Demo fiddle #3 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/cTFGUj).

Comment: This does seem to work perfectly, however I'm struggling to fully understand the code itself. I'll see if I can figure all this out.

Comment: @Daedalus - The converter works by serializing a [DTO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_transfer_object) with the necessary structure.  Then there's some extra complexity to prevent the converter from being recursively invoked to serialize the `DTO.Value`, which would result in a stack overflow exception.

Comment: Would this work fine if the "value" is something other than a string, like a bool/decimal/int?

Comment: @Daedalus - yes, it was designed to work for any type, just use the correct generic parameter for `TValue`, e.g. `WrapWithValueConverter<bool>`, `WrapWithValueConverter<decimal>`, `WrapWithValueConverter<int>` etc etc.

Comment: Ah okay, so if the returning object contains all of them, the annotation approach would be better?

Comment: Or you could add the multiple converters (`WrapWithValueConverter<bool>`, `WrapWithValueConverter<decimal>`, `WrapWithValueConverter<int>` and so on) to settings.  Or maybe you should be looking at a custom contract resolver to apply the converter(s) as required, a contract resolver can be a good way to apply wholescale transforms to your JSON.  See: [JSON.net ContractResolver vs. JsonConverter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41094764/3744182).  Can't say without a [mcve] so maybe you should ask a second question?

Comment: This is actually working perfectly, except for one edge case... I am working with Enum's, using the [EnumMember(Value = "X")] annotation. I've got it properly converting to the Member value with [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))], however its not being handled by the WrapWithValueConverter upon serialization.

Comment: *I've got it properly converting to the Member value with [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]* - How are you applying `[JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))]`?  Is it in settings?

Comment: I've added that annotation to the class member directly. I'm passing in the WrapWithValueConverter<string> into the converter settings in DeserializeObject call. My apologies, I meant Deserialization. Converting the object to a string. This specifically is Customer Status. The actual value that sits in JSON will be "A", but the Enum value is "ACTIVE".

Comment: *I've added that annotation to the class member* - you mean you applied it directly to the `enum` type, or to some field or property?  Can you share a [mcve]?

Comment: I can provide a MRE, but it'll take me a bit. In the meantime: I have `public enum CustomerStatus { [EnumMember(Value = "A")] ACTIVE }`. Then in my class I have `public class Customer { [JsonConverter(typeof(StringEnumConverter))] public CustomerStatus Status { get; set;} }`. Upon Deserialization, I do get the value "A", however its not wrapped with value.

Comment: I'm almost wondering if this is even worth the trouble, and if I should just make the datatype a string. I have a feeling this is more complicated than it realistically needs to be.

Comment: That's because converters applied to a property supersede converters applied in settings.  I mentioned that in the answer: *`// Here we take advantage of the fact that a converter applied to a property has highest precedence to avoid an infinite recursion.`*.  For confirmation see [C# JsonConvert using the default converter instead of the custom converter](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53401189/3744182).  If you need nested converters for your member you may need to apply the decorator pattern.  A [mcve] (or even a separate question) would help here.

Comment: @Daedalus - You could add `WrapEnumWithValueConverter<TEnum>` for enums that applies `StringEnumConverter` rather than `NoConverter` to the nested value.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/cTFGUj.  (If you also need to support nullable enums you might need to enhance it a bit.)

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much, I really appreciate the support!