# Want to assign HTML value to String variable

Tags: c#, html

I want to assign HTML snippet to string variable.
something like -

```
 string div = "<table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>"; // It should return only 'Hello'
```

Please suggest.

Comment: First someone will propose regex. Then that person will be murdered. Then someone will post a link to HtmlAgilityPack.

Comment: I don't see the question? You seem to have successfully put HTML into a string. How are you using the string?

Comment: At the risk of being murdered, this is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: Where are you getting the HTML from?  It might be easier to just pull out the text there.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        string div = "<table><tr><td>Hello</td></tr></table>"; // It should return only 'Hello

        var doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.LoadXml(div);
        string text = doc.InnerText;
```

Do you also need the Jquery version of this?

Comment: And yep, this will fail if the HTML isn't perfect XML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that the HTML won't change between the string you want to get, you can simply do a **Substring** between the two constants string and you will get your string into your variable.

```
        const string prefix = "<table>";
        const string suffix = "</table>";
        string s = prefix + "TEST" + suffix ;
        string s2 = s.Substring(prefix.Length, s.IndexOf(suffix, StringComparison.Ordinal) - prefix.Length);
```

Here is the **Regex** version:

```
        const string prefix = "<table>";
        const string suffix = "</table>";
        string s = prefix + "TEST" + suffix;
        string s2 = Regex.Match(s, prefix + "(.*)" + suffix).Groups[1].Value;
```