# Regular expressions - remove the tags

Tags: c#, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

I have to remove the tags and keep all the other information in a XML file. I am somehow at a loss when using regular expressions. I could only come up with reading the file line by line and then trying to "locate" all the tags and replace them with "" - empty strings. However, it is not working as expected:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, "<.*>", "");
```

Can I please get an explanation why this is not working as expected (I think it should just locate all possible combinations of symbols that are inside <>. Also, can you please recommend a good introduction to regular expressions. I read a lot at regular-expressions.info but I find it somehow incomplete and confusing.

Comment: Why don't you use a xml parser?

Comment: And what exactly do you want left behind? Everything but the `<` and `>`? Leave behind attributes? Leave behind CDATA and XText?

Comment: Removing `<>` from an XML file? Something tells me you are not on the optimal approach.

Comment: You're here mate [I need to Pound a nail, do I use a glass bottle or an old shoe?](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx) . . . tl;dr, this isn't the way to do this, use an Xml parser and output the new file with a sensible layout (and if that's with all attribute and node values on individual lines, then go with it)

Comment: Obligatory http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/284111

Answer (score 8):

You should make the * quantifier lazy so that it matches the next > and not the last one:

```
line = Regex.Replace(line, "<.*?>", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the futility of trying to parse XML with regular expression (somebody else will no doubt post that link), your problem is that `*` is *greedy*. It will match as much as it can between the first `<` and the last `>` in your document.

For example, if you have this:

```
<someTag>some stuff
```

Then it'll work fine.

However if you have this:

```
<someTag>some stuff</someTag>
```

Then it'll match the first `<` and the last `>` and hence remove the content between the tags.

One solution, as BlackBear suggested is to add `?` to `*` in order to make it *non-greedy*. This way it will match the smallest match possible instead of the largest.

But the better solution, as commented by I4V is to use an XML parser to parse XML.

Answer (score 1):

Why waste time with Regular Expressions when you should be using XML parsers?

```
using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml"))
{
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        switch (reader.NodeType)
        {
        case XmlNodeType.Text:
        case XmlNodeType.CDATA:
        case XmlNodeType.EntityReference:
        case XmlNodeType.Whitespace:
        case XmlNodeType.SignificantWhitespace:
           Console.Write("{0}", reader.ReadContentAsString());
           break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why wasting time with such a complicated code when you can do it with a simple one-liner thing? ;)

Comment: @BlackBear: because regex is a lazy and typically incorrect "solution" to these problems. All of the current answers will fail for XML elements which span multiple lines.

Comment: Yeah, agree on that, was just kidding ;) But using a full XML parser might be an overkill, it depends on what you want to do

Comment: More likely they need XSLT, and the above approach (or a similar approach using XLinq) takes little effort beyond the knowledge that regex will not work for this type of problem.