# Remove Style tag in HTML

Tags: c#, html, regex

I need to remove all style tags completely for the given HTML code. I found following regex to match entire style tag in the the XML. It works fine for the given Html code in online regex testers.

```
*style\s*=\s*('|")[^\2]*?\2([^>]*)*
```

However, through a C# code, it didn't work for the given HTML.

**Following is the C# code:**

```
Regex regex = new Regex("style\\s*=\\s*('|\")[^\\2]*?\\2([^>]*)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: A DOM parser may be better suited to this task.  Maybe something like the HTML Agility Pack?  http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com

Comment: Check this if that helps:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags ?

Comment: You can't use a backreference inside a character class

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Regex should be

```
 style\s*=\s*('|")[^\1]*\1
```

---

Though I would use [Htmlagilitypack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

```
   HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
   doc.Load(yourStream);
   var elementsWithStyleAttribute = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//@style");
   foreach (var element in elementsWithStyleAttribute)
   {
       element.Attributes["style"].Remove();
   }
   doc.Save();
```

Comment: Modified regex doesnt work. I just need to remove only the style attribute.

Comment: @Dimax show the exact code you are using to replace and also a sample of that html

Comment: Following is the code:

Regex regex = new Regex("style\\s*=\\s*('|\")[^\\2]*?\\2([^>]*)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

htmldoc.Content = regex.Replace(htmldoc.Content, string.Empty);


Sample Html Code:

<P style="MARGIN: 0in 0in 0pt 0.5in" class="MsoNormal">
  <SPAN style="FONT-FAMILY: 'Tw Cen MT Condensed Extra Bold'; COLOR: black; FONT-SIZE: 16pt; mso-bidi-font-family: Arial">
    There are numerous applications </SPAN></P>

Comment: @Dimax u r not using regex in ans

Comment: Hi Anirudh, sorry for the delay. i did the same using HtmlAgilityPack. Thnx for the sample code.

Answer (score 8):

I usually use the below code to remove inline styles, class, images and comments from an Outlook message prior to saving it into database:

```
desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "(<style.+?</style>)|(<script.+?</script>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "(<img.+?>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "(<o:.+?</o:.+?>)", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "<!--.+?-->", "", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "class=.+?>", ">", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
desc = Regex.Replace(desc, "class=.+?\s", " ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Singleline);
```

Comment: Please don't add the same answer to multiple questions. Answer the best one and flag the rest as duplicates. See [Is it acceptable to add a duplicate answer to several questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/104227)