# Html Agility Pack Text </form> Tags Remain

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I've tried two ways to get just the text from an HTML page with HTML Agility Pack:

**Method 1**

```
var root = doc.DocumentNode;

foreach (HtmlNode node in root.SelectNodes("//text()"))
{
    sb.AppendLine(node.InnerText.Trim() + " ");
}
```

**Method 2**

```
var root = doc.DocumentNode;
foreach (var node in root.DescendantsAndSelf())
{
    if (!node.HasChildNodes)
    {
        string text = node.InnerText;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            sb.AppendLine(text.Trim() + " ");
    }
}
```

Both of these will leave behind the `</form>` tags if they are present of the page.  For example, here's www.google.com:

```
"body": " Search Images Maps Play YouTube News Gmail Drive More Calendar
Translate Mobile Books Wallet Shopping Blogger Finance Photos Videos Docs 
Even more &raquo; Account Options Sign in Search settings Web History 
&times; Try a fast, secure browser with updates built in. Yes, get Chrome 
now &nbsp; Advanced search Language tools </form> Advertising Programs 
Business Solutions +Google About Google &copy; 2016 - Privacy - Terms "
```

What gives?

Edit:  By "Just the text" I mean "language text"....so:

`<i>book reports</i>` becomes `book reports`

`<a href="...">More Details</a>` becomes `More Details`

`<div>Check out our <b>deals</b>!</div>` becomes `Check out our deals!`

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "just the text"?  After all, html is just text. Do you mean just the content of each dom element? Or something else?

Comment: Maybe "language text" would be a better way to explain it.  The end result is that this will go into a database for site search.  I'll add some examples to the main question.

Answer (score 0):

Please search for your question before posting

[Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

Samples pulled from this webpage

```
String result = Regex.Replace(htmlDocument, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Or if you want to use Agility (also pulled from webpage)

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(Properties.Resources.HtmlContents);
var text = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//body//text()").Select(node => node.InnerText);
StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
foreach (string line in text)
{
   output.AppendLine(line);
}
string textOnly = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(output.ToString());
```