# regex replace to match everything including the angle brackets

Tags: c#, regex

My input is a string like the following-

```
some random text <http…any characters> more random text
```

or it could include https

```
some random text <https…any characters>  more random text
```

I want my output to replace anything "including" the angle brackets with nothing. So my output should be the following-

```
some random text more random text
```

I'm using C# to do this so here's an example of my code:

```
static string RemoveLinks(string source)
    {
        const string pattern = "Need Regex Pattern Here";

        return Regex.Replace(source, pattern, "");
    }
```

Can someone please help with a pattern match?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/787951/3832970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answer breaks if there are more than just one set of brackets. I would use this instead:

```
<[^>]+>
```

Essentially, the char class ensures that the match does not catch an ending `>`.

Depending on your needs, you may want to add some more to the regex:

```
<http[^>]+>
```

or, if you must ensure it's separated by spaces from the surrounding text:

```
(\s)<http[^>]+>(\s)
```

In that case, you would replace it with `$1$2` to ensure that the surrounding spaces are preserved. Or, if you just want a normal space instead, you can just use the string `" "`. (Obviously.)

---

Important: I recommend using raw strings, like `@"your regex with \backslashes"`, not regular strings.

Answer (score 0):

Go [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx) to get all that info.

Probably something like:

```
string pattern = "\s<.*>\s";
```

Would be correct. You can do some easy testing using Notepad++ since it has regex options in its find & replace tool. That way you can do a more accurate test and make sure it's all working correctly.

Comment: Need lazy quantifier `?`.