# Extract text from HTML String Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, content-management-system

I'm building a CMS and the content of a post is saved in HTML in the database.

On the page that lists posts, I would like to show the first n words / n characters, for the short version of the post with a "read more" button.

What would be the best way to strip the text from the HTML the right way, without making it look al weird?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags

Comment: read the html as a string, parse to AST, walk through tree and reduce all text nodes. https://github.com/fb55/htmlparser2

Answer (score 3):

you can try use the library html-to-text (npm install html-to-text). Split all text and show the n array elements.