# Regex to replace <img src value - C#

Tags: c#, html, .net, regex, src

I read HTML file and do some stuff. After reading the file, I have to write a C# code to replace src values for img tag only. Can someone suggest a piece of code replace src values? 
Please find a sample HTML code which I have.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
     <head>
     </head>
     <img alt="Mountain View" src="Tab1.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
     <img src="Tab2.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
     <img alt="Mountain View" src="Tab3.png" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
     <img src="Tab4.png" alt="Mountain View" style="width:304px;height:228px;">
     <a href="https://www.w3schools.com">Visit W3Schools</a>
     </body>
</html>
```

Comment: [don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787987/5174469) ;)

Comment: As @MongZhu said... don't do that.  Use the [HTML Agility Pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags/787987#787987).  It's what it's for.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the file line by line here is an example of how to replace the source with yours using regex:

```
string test = "<img alt=\"Mountain View\" src=\"Tab1.png\" style=\"width:304px;height:228px;\">";

string mySource = "src=\"Weird.png\" ";

string newtest = Regex.Replace(test, "src=\".+\"\\s",mySource);
```

still I would suggest to follow the answer that I linked in my comment