# How to converting a json with html tags to a csv using C#?

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, json.net

I am writing a customized translation tool that translates csv file content from one language to another via the new azure text translation API. Now the  problem is that one of the columns is html formatted

i.e  Descripción (html)

```
<p><span style='font-family:arial,helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:small;'>Paso hacia fuera en estilo y comodidad con estas bufandas de raso gasa estilo de alta calidad, hecho de material de alta calidad a precios asequibles. Tienda con idence.</span></p><li><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" font-size:small;=""><strong>Color:</strong> Crema y negro</span></li><span style="font-family:" arial,="" helvetica,="" sans-serif;="" font-size:="" small;=""> <strong>Color:</strong> crema &amp; negro</span>"....
```

Here is what am doing so far I Convert the csv to json format then translate to another language i.e (Spanish or German) then I get the response in Json format but when I am converting back the json to csv i get errors.

I have looked into the error and I found out that the column has double quotes which invalidates my json file. How can I escape/replace the html tags and the double quotes?

My English json (converts well to csv):

```
[{"SKU":"d2d Floppy Hats 91504 (One Size)",
"EAN":"123456789",
"Meta Description (website)":"Shop at dso. Product Features:
Colour: Slate Grey
Pattern: Spiral Plain Woven
Features: 
Material: 100% Paper",
"New From":"23/6/2017",
"New To":"23/7/2017",
"Description ( html)":"<p><span style='font-family:arial,helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:small;'>Step out in style &amp; comfort with these high quality Satin Chiffon Style scarves, made from top quality material at affordable prices. Shop with idence.</span></p><li><span style=font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:small;><strong>Colour:</strong> Cream &amp; Black</span></li><span style=font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: small;><strong>Colour:</strong> Cream &amp; Black</span></li>"
}]
```

Translated json (Spanish):

```
[{"SKU": "d2d disquete sombreros 91504 (talla única)",
"EAN": "123456789",
"Meta Description (sitio web)": "tienda en dso. Características del producto: color: patrón gris de la pizarra: espiral llano tejidos características: Material: 100% de papel ",
"Nuevo de": "23/06/2017",
"Nuevo a": "23/07/2017",
"Descripción (html)": "<p><span style='font-family:arial,helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:small;'>Paso hacia fuera en estilo y comodidad con estas bufandas de raso gasa estilo de alta calidad, hecho de material de alta calidad a precios asequibles. Tienda con idence.</span></p><li><span style="font-family:arial,helvetica,sans-serif;" font-size:small;=""><strong>Color:</strong> Crema y negro</span></li><span style="font-family:" arial,="" helvetica,="" sans-serif;="" font-size:="" small;=""> <strong>Color:</strong> crema &amp; negro</span>"
}]
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?

code for translating and getting the xmldocument. the json strings remains the same as provided above but i don't understand why extra double quotes and equal signs are included after translation

```
string txtToTranslate = txtjson.Text.ToString();
        if (txtToTranslate.ToString() == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No Json file to convert to csv");
        }
        else
        {
            string uri = string.Format("http://api.microsofttranslator.com/v2/Http.svc/Translate?text=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(txtToTranslate) + "&to={0}", languageCode);
            WebRequest translationWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(uri);
            translationWebRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", tokenProvider.GetAccessToken()); //header value is the "Bearer plus the token from ADM
            WebResponse response = null;
            response = translationWebRequest.GetResponse();
            Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream();
            Encoding encode = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");



            StreamReader translatedStream = new StreamReader(stream, encode);
            System.Xml.XmlDocument xTranslation = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
            xTranslation.LoadXml(translatedStream.ToString());


            string jsontranslated = xTranslation.OuterXml;                  

            txttranslated.Text = jsontranslated;
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

First remove all html Tags with regex ([see answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/787951/1903789) from [Daniel Brückner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/77507/daniel-br%C3%BCckner) ):

```
var  plainText= Regex.Replace(htmlDocument, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
```

Create a class for the translation

```
 public class Translation{
   public string PlainText{ get;set;} 
}
var translation = new Translation { PlainText = plainText};
```

You could use Newtonsoft for creating the Json:

```
var jsonSerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Error,
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};
var serializedTranslations = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(translation, jsonSerializerSettings);
```

Now your JSON should be correctly escaped.

Comment: Thanx for the response. i just edited the question by including my code snippet where i suspect i have some bug, could you help me out from there @codeHacker