# Remove Certain HTML tags in C#

Tags: c#, html, regex

I'm trying to remove a certain html tags in C# like this:

```
<div>
    <blockquote style="font-size: 30px" width="300px">
For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature. The world's leading conservation organization, WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by 1.2 million members in the United States and close to 5 million globally.
    </blockquote>
</div>
```

To be result as

```
<div>For 50 years, WWF has been protecting the future of nature. The world's leading conservation organization, WWF works in 100 countries and is supported by 1.2 million members in the United States and close to 5 million globally.</div>
```

So far, I'm trying to do the regex. `(<.+?)\s+style\s*=\s*([""']).*?\2(.*?>)` but this is only for removing the style but I'm not sure how can I able to achieve the result that I want.

Thanks!

Comment: What's your criteria forming the start of what's you want to extract ?  In this case 'organization,...' which can vary for different contents, so how do you cut the text ?

Comment: Greetings @SeaBean I updated the question. sorry for the confusion

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using C# regular expressions to remove HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787932/using-c-sharp-regular-expressions-to-remove-html-tags)

Comment: But I need to have a way to remove an html tags for a certain tags, for my example, it's the `<blockquote>`

Comment: Use an XML Parser. Move the text-node one level up, remove the blockquote node, save, done.

Comment: do you have sample for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can see, you want to remove the HTML elements that contain a `style` attribute, also remove their closing pairs. Unfortunately, there is no good way to do that with regexes. Without the 'also remove their closing pairs' clause, we could write an approximately good regex.

On the other hand, `XSLT` is the right tool for this, because it can handle the recursive nature of XML:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="//*[not(@style)]">

    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What's happening here? The `<xsl:template match="//*[not(@style)]">` part matches everything that does not have a `style` attribute. Then the `<xsl:copy>...</xsl:copy>` part copies them entirely. I.e. the items that have a `style` attribute, they will not be copied.

For the record, this is a slight variant of the XSLT identity transformation:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```